# Button is not disabled in jasmine test, but is disabled when viewing application

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a test that ensures a submit button is disabled until the form is valid.  If I browse the application and manually test it, it works as expected; however, it my test, when I use the Karma "debug" link the button is not disabled so the test fails, why is this?

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>

      <div>
        <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let choice of question.choices">
          <input
            ngModel
            required
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="questionChoices"
            id="choice-{{ choice.id }}"
            value="{{ choice.id }}"
          >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="choice-{{ choice.id }}">
            {{ choice.label }}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
<!-- Note that I'm including both disabled=... and [disabled]=... here only to convey that they both work separately, I don't use them together -->
      <button
        disabled="{{ form.invalid ? 'disabled' : ''}}"
        [disabled]="form.invalid"
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit</button>
</form>
```

The test is

```
it('should disable submit button until form is valid', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QuestionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.question = mockData.question[1].data[0];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('[type="submit"]').disabled).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

Here is the component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Question } from '../../../models/question.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  question: Question;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Again, when I view the application in browser the button is disabled as expected until I complete the required field.  However, when I load it in Karma it is not

[image]

So I'm guessing that my implementation of the component, the test, or both is wrong :D.

Comment: What does your component look like? Is it possible `question.choices` is populated asynchronously?

Comment: I added the component code - in real life the question is passed from the parent component which loads the question from a service.  In the test, I'm just loading it from a local json file